# Android: List all gallery apps and camera to choose picture from

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore

I am trying to choose Image from Camera or Gallery and using the following code and want all the gallery options be be availble in the first chooser screen instead of being clubbed under another option.

```kotlin
open fun getImageFromPhone() {
        val pickIntent = Intent()
        pickIntent.type = "image/*"
        pickIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        val galleryIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        )
        galleryIntent.setType("image/gallery");
        val pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"
        var outputFileUri: Uri? = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile(TEMP_FILE, EXTENSION))
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle)
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(takePhotoIntent, galleryIntent))
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri)
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CODE_IMG_GALLERY)
    }
```

This leads to showing the following options:
[image]

On clicking on `Android System` I get the gallery options:
[image]

However, I want these options(in the above image) to be listed as separate options in the first menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to select image source from camera's `(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` or gallery `(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`. I have posted all related methods, it works perfectly. Just call this Intent as below:

```
startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(activity,"Your Title",false),PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE)

   

    public static Intent getPickImageChooserIntent(@NonNull Context context, CharSequence 
    title, boolean includeDocuments) {
    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    // collect all camera intents if Camera permission is available
    if (!isExplicitCameraPermissionRequired(context)) {
      allIntents.addAll(getCameraIntents(context, packageManager));
    }
    List<Intent> galleryIntents =
            getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,includeDocuments);
    if (galleryIntents.size() == 0) {
      // if no intents found for get-content try pick intent action (Huawei P9).
      galleryIntents = getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_PICK, includeDocuments);
    }
    allIntents.addAll(galleryIntents);

    Intent target;
    if (allIntents.isEmpty()) {
      target = new Intent();
    } else {
      target = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
      allIntents.remove(allIntents.size() - 1);
    }

    // Create a chooser from the main  intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(target, title);

    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
    }

    public static boolean isExplicitCameraPermissionRequired(@NonNull Context context) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
        && hasPermissionInManifest(context, "android.permission.CAMERA")
        && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

        /** Get all Camera intents for capturing image using device camera apps. */
    public static List<Intent> getCameraIntents(
            @NonNull Context context, @NonNull PackageManager packageManager) {
  
      List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
  
      // Determine Uri of camera image to  save.
      Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri(context);
  
      Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
      for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        if (outputFileUri != null) {
          intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        }
        allIntents.add(intent);
      }
  
      return allIntents;
    }
    /**
     * Get all Gallery intents for getting image from one of the apps of the device that handle
     * images.
     */
    public static List<Intent> getGalleryIntents(
            @NonNull PackageManager packageManager, String action, boolean includeDocuments) {
      List<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<>();
      Intent galleryIntent =
              action == Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                      ? new Intent(action)
                      : new Intent(action, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
      List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
      for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        intents.add(intent);
      }
      // remove documents intent
      if (!includeDocuments) {
        for (Intent intent : intents) {
          if (intent
                  .getComponent()
                  .getClassName()
                  .equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
            intents.remove(intent);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return intents;
    }

        /**
     * Get URI to image received from capture by camera.
     *
     * @param context used to access Android APIs, like content resolve, it is your
     *     activity/fragment/widget.
     */
    public static Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri(@NonNull Context context) {
      Uri outputFileUri = null;
      File getImage = context.getExternalCacheDir();
      if (getImage != null) {
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
      }
      return outputFileUri;
    }
```